# Removing padded zeroes in Hexadecimal data in C?

Tags: c

I am getting hexdata string after scanning the bio-template data. I need to remove these zeroes just so I have the hexadecimal string. The problem is I cannot just remove pairs of zeroes as the string may have zeroes in the middle.

Also as if zeros are removed by some way string length has to be kept according to hex format; means last zero can be the part of data but not all the zeros.
Data look like this:

```
1EBC67E66B1FE9C783000C700DBBF0000000000000
```

Last zero after 'F' can also be the part of data.

Comment: Can you predict in advance the length of the data you will get ? If no, this should mean that the 0 you get at the end are meaningful. Please try to make it clearer.
May be you meant that you cannot have a pair of zero at the end ?

Comment: If you can use a tool like sed(1) to process the data as text beforehand, just a `sed -e 's;\(00\)*$;;'` should do... if you really require C, start at the end of the string and lop off pairs of zeroes until hitting a pair that isn't "00".

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Can you provide some examples of input + desired output please?

Answer (score 1):

Why not going over the string from its end to the start, jumping in 2 each time till the first non-zero value, and then copy the substring (till the first non-zero value location found)?

Comment: Problem is that with this solution if I am jumping by 2 each time after '83' in the given data there are '000' zeros. By detecting them by code will exit & rest of the string wasted.